# Finding the replacement of the SOAP APIs for WSO2 identity server for 6.0.0 version in Account recovery API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

As part of WSO2 identity server 6.0.0, SOAP APIs are deprecated and recommended to use REST-based APIs. We are using `RemoteUserStoreManagerService.wsdl` and `UserIdentityManagementAdminService.wsdl` SOAP APIs in our project, and want to replace the SOAP APIs with recommended REST APIs. Can you help us to find the list of REST APIs to replace `RemoteUserStoreManagerService.wsdl` and `UserIdentityManagementAdminService.wsdl` SOAP APIs. The APIs document is not clear.

We need a replacement for the reset-password API, among the APIs provided in the https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/apis/restapis/account-recovery.yaml there isn't an API that can reset the password when the user is already logged-in in the system. We have /set-password API which is dependent on the /recover-password API. The key received from the /recover-password is been used to `/set-password` . Is there an API available which will help user to reset the password where already knows its old password just need to reset it with some other password.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [SCIM2 Me endpoint](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/#/Me%20Endpoint/patchUserMe) (https://localhost:9443/scim2/Me) PATCH operation to update the password.

Authenticate the request using the logging user's credentials.

```
{
    "Operations": [
        {
            "op": "replace",
            "value": {
                "password": "newpassword"
            }
        }
    ],
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
    ]
}
```